# Can't exit git master branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github, bitbucket, railstutorial.org

I am currently using the cloud9 IDE and am working with a git repository in a terminal window. I am trying to return to the command line interface but I cannot seem to exit the "(master)" branch. I have tried `:q`, `:quit`, `ctrl+c`, and many others but I cannot seem to leave the git editor.

How do I exit the git environment so that I can return back to the original command line interface?

```
maclin@rails:~/workspace/example (master) $
```

Comment: That sounds like your shell is configured to show the current git branch - there's nothing to exit from

Comment: Thanks @FrederickCheung I was able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 1):

You're not in any git environment, you're still using the shell but have some git prompt installed in you're shell, such as described here: http://code-worrier.com/blog/git-branch-in-bash-prompt/

Comment: ok, now i see the problem. But now how would I got about "uninstalling" the git prompts from that shell? Id like to run a (group :production do) command and it will not allow me to do so

Comment: it depends on which git shell is installed, you should be able to e.g. set or unset a environment variable, I personally don't use such shells, I always know where in git I am ;-) sorry

Answer (score 0):

It is reporting the branch that you are in at the command line.

If you don't want to be in that project, you can change your folder.

If you want to be in the project, but don't want to be in that branch, change branches.

You are apparently confusing feedback from your prompt to being 'in' git.

You aren't 'in' git, but just in the terminal using a shell, that has a prompt that is giving you feedback about the repository you are using.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with git repository, by default you are on the master branch. You can always create new branch and checkout to that. I assume you are confused with the working part of git. Read [Git Basics to start](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) .

If you exit from the git folder, you are out of git environment as you understand it but anyways you are always in the same terminal using shell.

Answer (score 0):

just get out throught cd c, even whether doesn't work